# How I could calculate packet loss in ns-3

Tags: ns-3

I am absolute beginner in ns-3. How to add code to calculate packet loss in tcp-variants-comparison.cc and store instantaneous results in a file to let me plot it per simulation time.

Answer (score 0):

Check Flow Monitor (chapter 16 of the ns3-model-library)

https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/flow-monitor.html

The simple version is, use this code at the end of your script to put information about your flows (dropped packets, delays, jitters...) in a .xml file

```
  FlowMonitorHelper flowHelper;
  Ptr<FlowMonitor> flowMonitor = flowHelper.InstallAll();
  Simulator::Stop(Seconds(stopSim));
  Simulator::Run ();
  flowMonitor->SerializeToXmlFile("flowmonitor.xml", false, true);
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

You need to explicitly instruct the simulator to stop because the flowmonitor will keep generating events (it'll constantly check for dropped packets) otherwise the simulation will not end.

Comment: Thank you. I want script in the main code to calculate packet drop without using FlowMonitor and store the result in a file as function of simulation time.